# Capture parameters in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

suppose this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/articles/1111/comments/
```

i'd like to get all comments for a given article (here the 1111).

This is how i capture this url:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<uid>[-\w]+)/comments/$', comments_views.CommentList.as_view()),
```

The related view looks like to:

```
class CommentList(generics.ListAPIView):    
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = "uid"

    def get_queryset(self):
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(article= ???)
        return comments
```

For information, the related serializer

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'owner', 'created_at')
```

As you can see, I've updated my get_queryset to filter comments on the article but I don't know how to catch the "uid" parameter.
With an url ending with ?uid=value, i can use self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('uid') but in my case, I don't know how to do it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The url parameter is stored in `self.kwargs`. `lookup_field` is the field (defaults to pk) the generic view uses inside the ORM when looking up individual model instances, `lookup_url_kwarg` is probably the property you want.

So try the following:

```
class CommentList(generics.ListAPIView):    
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_url_kwarg = "uid"

    def get_queryset(self):
        uid = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(article=uid)
        return comments
```

Comment: thanks !! i've tried unsuccessfully to build a custom mixins (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#customizing-the-generic-views) but your solution works fine. :)

Comment: You may want to explore this library which takes `query params` and put filters on `queryset` in an elegant way. https://github.com/manjitkumar/drf-url-filters

Comment: Hey @Scott Woodall, I had a similar problem, now I sorted it out. My concern here now is, is this `lookup_url_kwarg` a must? How about if I I'm having multiple params? e.g `uid`, `some_thing_else`? Is it ok to just do this way  `comments = Comment.objects.filter(article=self.kwargs.get('uid'))` ?