# Django-rest-framework read url data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('fan/<str:name>', FanView)

urlpatterns = [
   path(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

view.py

```
class FanView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Fan.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FanSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Fan.objects.all()
    print(self.request.query_params.get('name', None))
    return queryset
```

Hi i am trying to send name in djnago-rest-framework url.
And reading the same in my viewSet.

But, i am always getting None.

I don't wants to send data like fan/?name=foo

Please have a look

Is there any way to achive that ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to access is not in `query_params`. This is a url parameter and is stored in `self.kwargs.lookup_field`. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292646/capture-parameters-in-django-rest-framework) how to access the url parameter.

Comment: Can i mention query params in my urls like fan/?name=foo

Comment: Yes, but for that, you should remove `<str:name>` from `router.register`

Comment: OK, how i can define it in urls.py ?