# Unable to fetch parameters from Django URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am using Django REST Framework and I want to fetch the two parameters entered in the URL.

My URL is:

> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/colleges/slug2/courses/sug1/`

where **'slug2'** and **'sug1'** are the two *slug* parameters entered.

I want to retrieve those two parameters in my ModelViewSet

views.py

```
class CollegeCourseViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            slug1 = self.kwargs.get('slug1')
            slug2 = self.kwargs.get('slug2')
            print(slug2)
            queryset = Course.objects.filter(slug=slug2)
            return Response(CollegeCourseSerializer(queryset, many=True).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'courses', CollegeCourseViewSet, basename='college_course_list')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/colleges/<slug:slug>/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

But slug2 outputs None and hence the problem.

Is there any specific way to obtain those parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to get query parameter using name `slug2`, but your url patter define only `slug` argument.

Comment: I included a lookup_field in the ViewSet so it gives the second slug when entered.

Comment: `lookup_field` related to model field to lookup - > `slug` field in url, so still you can't get any `slug2` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was trying to retrieve the slug of the lookup_field as well in the params. But it is related to model and not a parameter, rightly pointed out in the comments.

So I just accessed it by the *lookup_url_kwarg* field in the ModelViewSet.

For more details refer :
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293784/11102816)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            slug1 = self.kwargs.get('slug1') 
            slug2 = self.kwargs.get('slug2')
            queryset = Course.objects.filter(slug2=slug2)
            return Response(CollegeCourseSerializer(queryset, many=True).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In your urls.py, I am only seeing 1 slug being passed `i.e slug not slug1`. So, if you want to parse another slug then you might need to add that in your URLs and then parse it in the view.
If you want your URL to look like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/colleges/slug2/courses/slug1/
```

Then you have to change your urls.py to

```
 path('api/v1/colleges/<slug:slug2>/course/<slug:slug1>/', include(router.urls)),
```